# JPA 2.1 - unidirectional container-->element reference with element as owner?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, one-to-one

I have a Container, which references an Element, with e.g.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
Element element;
```

Is it possible to make the Element the owner of the relationship without explicitly assigning the Container to the element?

In my usecase, Element is abstract and has different subtypes and the Container is embedded in another Entity Root.

In my "solution" the Containers reverence is inverse (`mappedBy="rootRef"`) and the Element references Root. Then this rootRef has to be set when a container is added to the root, e.g. with `container.element.setRootRef(this)`. It can't be in the Container, because the Container is created before Root. To me this looks like a really ugly solution for a simple problem.

How do make my code beautiful?

Comment: And why does it trouble you so much if the element has the OneToOne to Container. You can mark the access protected/private if you don't want to have it visible to the world. On the DB level no extra data are needed.

Comment: A OneToOne wouldn't trouble me - what does is that I need to modify the setter of the containers container to set this reference, so that hibernate persists it properly.